# Why does a single structured query run multiple SQL queries per batch?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Why does the following structured query run multiple SQL queries as can be seen in web UI's SQL tab?

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val rates = spark.
  readStream.
  format("rate").
  option("numPartitions", 1).
  load.
  writeStream.
  format("console").
  option("truncate", false).
  option("numRows", 10).
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds)).
  queryName("rate-console").
  start
```

[image]

Comment: What does your DAG visualization look like?

Comment: It does **not** matter since DAGs are **after** the queries. A SQL query can be zero or more Spark jobs and DAGs are afterwards, aren't they? Or you think about another DAG.

Comment: No need to use bold :) I just didn't know that a single query can be more than one job. How does that work exactly? I thought the graph defines the query, which then is executed by the scheduler.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorry Yuval. Didn't mean to **bold** you :) I'm working on the answer as we speak, and suffice to say that the answer depends on the source(s) and the sink (so it's not obvious without reviewing the internals of each). In this case ConsoleSink triggers two queries by design.

Comment: Aha, OK. Waiting for your answer.